# how to hide the inline Vf from the pagelayout for some profiles

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, inline-visualforce

Requirement:I have Account pagelayout with the Inline VF Page ,I want to show this inline vf page for certain profiles and but for other profiles the inline vf page needs to be hide .
Please suggest

Comment: you can go with the different pagelayout option. if not then you can hide the vf page content using render option in vf page. I will not recommend this solution but in case if you are looking for this solution

Answer (score 0):

You can use different record types for different profile. Assign them with page layouts to hide or show the vf page.

Comment: Technically it is different page layouts for each recordtype. You do not need multiple record types.

Comment: Eric, you can put this as answer

Comment: @Eric One page layout to show vf page and another one to show it.

Comment: Yup. That's what I said. Not what your answer says though. I figured it was what you meant which is why I commented

Comment: @Reshma Eric's comment is correct. Your answer basically has no issue, but there is no need to create record types for this purpose.